# What's the differences and advantages to using functions and variable functions?

Tags: javascript

I was reading about this on W3, but I want to know more information about the differences and advantages of declaring a regular function versus  declaring a function stored in a variable.

Regular:

```
function test(){
   // code
}
```

With Variable:

```
var test = function() {
  // code
}
```

Comment: **Both** of those pieces of code will store a function in a variable named `test`.

Answer (score 0):

It mostly comes to Javascript hoisting.

> Hoisting is JavaScript's default behavior of moving declarations to the top.

Learn more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp)

Basically what it means:

> Inevitably, this means that no matter where functions and variables are declared, they are moved to the top of their scope regardless of whether their scope is global or local.
>
> Of note, however, is the fact that the hoisting mechanism only moves the declaration. The assignments are left in place.